# Allocating gender variable to new column

Tags: r, data.table

I kind of have a noob question related to R.
I have the following data table:

```
Receiver_id   Sender_id    Gender_receiver
1             2             Male
2             3             Female
3             4             Male
4             2             Female
5             3             Female
```

The receiver_id indicates the id_number of the person who received a message, whereas the inviter_id indicates the id_number of the person who send the message. In this case, person 2 sends something to person 1. The gender_receiver refers to the gender of the receiver. However, based on this it should be possible to also indicate the gender of the sender by creating a new column named Gender_sender. Unfortunately, I am not able to do so. I used the following code but without any success:

```
  dt[, Gender_sender := dt$Gender_receiver, by=Sender_id]
```

I do not get the right allocation of gender.

Somebody knows what I should do, I think it is relatively simple but I cannot figure it out.

Thanks in advance,
Amanda

Answer (score 6):

You need to match the Gender with id of sender:

```
dt[, Gender_sender:=Gender_receiver[match(Sender_id, Receiver_id)]]
dt
#   Receiver_id Sender_id Gender_receiver Gender_sender
#1:           1         2            Male        Female
#2:           2         3          Female          Male
#3:           3         4            Male        Female
#4:           4         2          Female        Female
#5:           5         3          Female          Male
```